# Why in geometric formula definitions do they not exclude the negatives in the domain or use an absolute value?

Tags: summation, notation, absolute-value, geometric-series

In resources like Wikipedia the following equation holds for $k>0$.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{k} [x^n]=\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}\hspace{1cm}x\neq1
\end{equation}
If you put the right hand side in a limit it holds for $k\geq0$. But why do we  rarely show the bounds of the k value and why not put the k  in an absolute value on the right hand side (Other than the aversion to absolute values)?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen sigma notation of the form $\sum_{i=p}^qa_i$ with $q < p$. Most people use the convention that $q \geq p$, so in this case, $k \geq 0$.

Comment: I have seen it a few times when people reindex the bounds of summation but, mostly on reindexing practice sheets.

Comment: The extra generality obtained by replacing $k$ by $|k|$ would be spurious and misleading: the formula as it stands does not hold for negative $k$. By the way, it is always useful to provide a specific reference rather than give a generalised reference to "most resources".

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I think your claim is a hard one to prove. If I see $\sum_p^q$, I make no assumptions about $p$ and $q$ other than the ones I see written down by the author (and the convention that if $q < p$, then the sum  is $0$).

Comment: I changed it so there is at least one specific reference.

Comment: But the Wikipedia article on  [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Formal_definition) specifically talks about the cases when (in your case) $k < 0$ in its formal definition of the notation. Just pointing at "the Wikipedia" is not a specific reference.

Comment: Oops, I skimmed over it. The main sources I am talking about are Math is Fun and this pdf :http://homepages.gac.edu/~holte/courses/mcs256/documents/summation/top10sums.pdf. Mostly the pdf since it features stuff like hyper geometric series.

Comment: OK. I think a large part of the answer is that even people tabulating mathematical formulas with lists of constraints are prone to leave out the constraints that they think are "obvious" or "standard". People are fallible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question

> But why do we rarely show the bounds of the k value

is one about conventions and expectations which is a common situation.

For example, to use an authoritative source, the
[DLMF section 1.2.11](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.2.E11) states explicitly

> $$a+ax+ax^2+\cdots+ax^{n-1}=\frac{a(1-x^n)}{1-x},\qquad x\ne1. $$

and also in a mouse popup states in reference to
[DLMF section 1.1 Special Notation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.1#p2.t1.r5) that

> $m,n\quad$ nonnegative integers, unless specified otherwise.

Notice that in the summation the DLMF decided to use an explicit sum
with $\,\cdots\,$ instead of using summation notation. Both choices
are valid and, in some cases, both are used for clarity.

A much less popular choice would have been to use a convention such that
$$ s_n := \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \quad \text{ where }\quad s_n = s_{n-1} +
 a_n,\quad s_0=a_0 $$ and which is supposed to be true for **all**
integer $\,n.\,$ For example, your case of
$$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\quad\text{ where }\quad x\ne1 $$ is true for **all** integer $\,n\,$ by this convention and would be
assumed as such in this context by this convention without being
specifically mentioned explicitly. No need to use absolute value for $n$.

Your further question

> and why not put the k in an absolute value on the right hand side

is simply because, in the common convention, $\,k\,$ is always assumed
to be nonnegative. Therefore, the equation is only assumed to be valid
for those $\,k\,$ although it may be valid outside that range using an
alternative convention.

Answer (score 1):

The answers come from what Rob Arthan said in the comments.

People tend to leave out constraints that are assumed.

As for the second part of the question being too general in an equation overcomplicates it and can have the affect of confusing the reader.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.